# Не проходит гет запрос при запуске пул потоков

Tags: c#, многопоточность

Есть метод `Get2`

```
 static void Get2(object x)
        {
            using (var request = new HttpRequest())
            {

                double n = Convert.ToDouble(x);

                request.UserAgent = Http.ChromeUserAgent();

                request.Cookies = cookies;
                request.AllowAutoRedirect = false;

                var res = request.Get("http://ru.stackoverflow.com");
                Console.WriteLine(x);
            }
        }
```

вызываю его используя пул потоков (нужно вызвать метод несколько раз и как можно быстрее)

```
 num = 1000;
 numto = 10000;
 while (num < numto)
            {

                for (int i = 0; i < 500; i++)
                {
                    ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem(new WaitCallback(Get2), num);
                    num++;
                }
            }
```

цикл `while` проходит меньше, чем за секунду, но вот в методе доходит до гет запроса и дальше не хочет идти                 `Console.WriteLine(x);`- не выводит, смотрел сниффером, гет запрос не проходит. 
Но, если вызвать метод с помощью `Thread`

```
  for (int i = 0; i < 500; i++)
            {
                Thread myThread = new Thread(new ParameterizedThreadStart(Get2));
                myThread.Start(num);
                num++;
            }
```

То все работает, гет запрос проходит. Только проблема в том, что этот способ гораздо больше тратит времени (т.к потоки создаются, а не используются готовые и тп). Можете подсказать, как решить проблему с пулом потоков ?

UPD:
т.к не нашел решения данной проблемы использовал вместо xNEt стандартный HttpWebRequest и все решилось

Answer (score 0):

> ```
> var res = request.Get("http://ru.stackoverflow.com");
> ```

Вероятно, тут пары using'ов не хватает - на ответ и на его Stream.

Количество одновременных запросов ограничено значением [`ServicePointManager.DefaultConnectionLimit`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.servicepointmanager.defaultconnectionlimit.aspx).

Comment: Вероятно, тут пары using'ов не хватает - на ответ и на его Stream.
можно по подробнее ? это разве объясняет, что, если по другому запустить, то все норм ? 

Количество одновременных запросов ограничено константой ServicePointManager.DefaultConnectionLimit.

Можете подсказать другой способ, для более быстрой обработки данной задачи ?

Comment: @Lolidze, ну с константой я что-то перестарался. Там свойство, которое можно устанавливать. Не знаю, как это объясняет с потоками - наверное, действительно нет. Но незакрытые соединения тоже считаются, поэтому в случае отсутствия using'а ограничение просто исчерпывается несколькими запросами, а остальные ждут.. эм.. вероятно, пока сборщик мусора соберёт другие объекты, а там вообще неясно, соберёт ли он их. http://bbs.vbstreets.ru/viewtopic.php?f=2&t=43360 - загляни.